# Manually clicking on a link, but textbox value not being posted back

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webforms, postback

I have a search page, you input some text in the input box and click search.  It shows you the search results.  The search click in just a href tag.

I have to perform a search manually sometimes i.e. without the user clicking on the search link.

So I did this via jQuery:

```
$("#hrefId").click();
```

The page posts back fine, but for some reason the value in the textbox is not being used by the search.

What could be the reason?

**Update**
The outputted HTML for the link looks like:

```
<a id="ctl00_content_ctl00_fragment_2657_ctl00_ctl01_ctl00_SearchButton" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$content$ctl00$fragment_2657$ctl00$ctl01$ctl00$SearchButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">Search</a>
```

Comment: love the control id....webforms eh!!!

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing there is binding the click event (overriding an already bound one would be my guess).

Try `$("#hrefId").trigger("click");`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the form field isn't being passed through, but another work around is to call the postback method directly in the JavaScript, something like:

```
__doPostBack('<%= hrefId.UniqueID %>','');
```